# Creating a UI for Python Program using tkinter. The button in Tkinter can be pressed multiple times. How can I create a "One Process" Pop Up?

Tags: python, python-3.x, button, tkinter, messagebox

Here is the simple UI with my attempt for this...

```
import tkinter as ttk
import subprocess
import sys
import time
import os
import tkinter.font as font
from tkinter import messagebox
from tkinter.ttk import *

app = ttk.Tk()

app.geometry("400x400")
app.configure(bg='gray')

photo = ttk.PhotoImage(file=r"C:\Users\ex\ex_button_active.png")
myFont = font.Font(family='Helvetica', size=20, weight='normal')

ttk.Label(app, text='Ex', bg='gray', font=(
    'Verdana', 15)).pack(side=ttk.TOP, pady=10)
app.iconbitmap(r'C:\Users\ex\ex_icon.ico')


def ex_activation():
    global pro
    print("Running program!")
    pro = subprocess.Popen("python programex.py", shell=True)


def ex_stop():
    global pro
    print("Stopping Program... Please Wait!")
    os.kill(pro.pid, 0)


ex_activation_button = ttk.Button(app, bg='black', image=photo, width=120, height=120, command=ex_activation)
ex_activation_button += 1
if ex_activation_button < 1:
    messagebox.showinfo("showinfo", "In Order to Run Again, Press ""Stop Program""")

ex_stop_button = ttk.Button(app, bg='Gray', text='Stop Program', width=12, command=ex_stop, height=3)

ex_stop_button['font'] = myFont

app.title("Ex")
ex_activation_button.pack(side=ttk.TOP)
ex_stop_button.pack(side=ttk.LEFT)

# app.mainloop()
while True:
    try:
        app.update()
        app.update_idletasks()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        pass
```

The goal here is to add a "One Process Only" Warning when the button is clicked more than once. The real question is how would I reset this counter for the number of times the start button was clicked after the stop button is clicked. This is a looping program and that is the reason I have a stop button. Any help greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can disable the button by change it's state.  After disabled, the button cannot be clicked.

```py
# disable a button:
ex_activation_button['state'] = 'disabled'

# re-enable the button:
ex_activation_button['state'] = 'normal'



# here is the change you need to add:
def ex_activation():
    global pro
    print("Running program!")
    ex_activation_button['state'] = 'disabled'
    pro = subprocess.Popen("python programex.py", shell=True)

def ex_stop():
    global pro
    print("Stopping Program... Please Wait!")
    os.kill(pro.pid, 0)
    ex_activation_button['state'] = 'normal'
```

Comment: Hey! Thanks for your answer. The issue is that I want the button to work again once stop button is pressed. Is this possible?

Comment: @RedgarPro Yes, it's possible, you can just use `ex_activation_button['state'] = 'normal'` inside your stop button command function `ex_stop`.